# Passing GIT_COMMIT value as a parameter to a freestyle job from a pipeline job in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job which is executing on a Linux node. It checks out the HEAD of develop and does it's thing. It then calls a freestyle job to be executed on a windows box. I want to make sure that the freestyle job ends up using the same GIT_COMMIT hash the pipeline job is using. My thought is to define a parameter (COMMIT) to the value of ${GIT_COMMIT}. The other parameters I'm passing over appear to be working just fine.

Below is a code block of my failed attempt:

```
def BRANCH_NAME = "develop"
def SW_VERS_PREFIX = "${BRANCH_NAME}_BUILD"
def TS = new Date()
def TS_FORMATTED = TS.format("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
def SW_VERS = "2.2.6.0.${TS_FORMATTED}"
def COMMIT = ""

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'centosdevbox'
        }
    }
    stages {

        stage ('Checkout develop branch') {
            steps {
                git branch: "develop",
                credentialsId: 'builder',
                    url: 'ssh://git@fqdn:7999/proj/repo.git'
            }
        }

        stage ('Build Freestyle Job Test') {
            steps {
                build job: 'param_pass_test', parameters: [
                    string (name: "BRANCH_NAME", value: "${BRANCH_NAME}"),
                    string (name: "SW_VERS_PREFIX", value: "${SW_VERS_PREFIX}"),
                    string (name: "SW_VERS", value: "${SW_VERS}"),
                    string (name: "COMMIT", value: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}")]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Although I think it would still be useful to figure out how to do what I'm describing above, I have moved on to a different solution. I'm adding the freestyle build portion to my Linux pipeline. It appears to be working just fine.